# How to set a custom ErrorReportValve in Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6

I want to set a custom `ErrorReportValve`. How do I do that?

Comment: I have changed to question because I had a different intention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set a custom `ErrorReportValve`:

1. Create a JAR with your custom valve
2. Put it into `$CATALINA_BASE/lib`
3. Add the `errorReportValveClass` to your `Host` element
4. Restart your Tomcat

Comment: Ok... And if I set it to `privileged` - what's next? Where/How do I access it? What I really want, in the bottom line, is to set the host's `ErrorReportValve`. Thank you though!

Comment: If you want to modify that you don't the priviliged attribute. I have a custom error valve too. Create a JAR with your custom valve, put it into `$CATALINA_BASE/lib` add the [`errorReportValveClass`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/host.html#Standard_Implementation) in your `Host` element.